# CS0433: The type 'CrystalDecisions.Web.CrystalReportViewer' exists in both

Tags: asp.net, crystal-reports

I am getting the following error while running crystal report

> CS0433: The type 'CrystalDecisions.Web.CrystalReportViewer' exists in
>   both
>   'c:\windows\assembly\GAC_MSIL\CrystalDecisions.Web\10.5.3700.0__692fbea5521e1304\CrystalDecisions.Web.dll'
>   and 'c:\windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\Temporary ASP.NET
>   Files\root\f8ac550c\d919c1f5\assembly\dl3\21892670\002d6cd3_f2bfc501\CrystalDecisions.Web.DLL

I am getting the above error after converting from framework 2.0 to 3.5. If I am creating new web application, I am not getting any error. I am getting error only for the converted application.

Answer (score 7):

Atlast I found..
The Problem is, 
In bin folder there is CrystalDecisions.Web.dll of version 10.2.51014.0 while i am adding reference i am adding 10.5.3700.0. So i have deleted dll from bin folder..Now Its working fine..

Thanks

Comment: Glad you solved it. Would you click the check mark next to this answer to indicate you've solved the problem?

Comment: This worked for me too. I had multiple versions of Crystal Reports installed. (32 bit and 64 bit) and there were some CrystalReport dlls remaining in the BIN folder even though I clean and build the solution. I deleted them and works now.

Answer (score 2):

In case you compiled older Crystal Report Viewer dotNET project (2.0 or 3.5) in Visual Studio 2013 (dotNET 4.0 or 4.5) and get the same error, my solution is to specify in the web.config the binding redirect of Crystal DLLs to the specific version.
More info at:
[MSDN: Redirecting Assembly Versions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7wd6ex19(v=vs.110).aspx)

Prerequsite:
Installed [SAP Crystal Reports, developer version for Microsoft Visual Studio, Support Pack 14 - v.13.0.14.1720](http://downloads.businessobjects.com/akdlm/cr4vs2010/CRforVS_13_0_14.exe) from the [SAP support page](http://scn.sap.com/docs/DOC-7824)

```
<runtime>
<assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
  <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="CrystalDecisions.Web" publicKeyToken="692FBEA5521E1304"/>
    <!-- Assembly versions can be redirected in app, 
      publisher policy, or machine configuration files. -->
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="10.0.0.0-12.0.0.0" newVersion="13.0.2000.0"/>
  </dependentAssembly>
</assemblyBinding>
<assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
  <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="CrystalDecisions.Shared" publicKeyToken="692FBEA5521E1304"/>
    <!-- Assembly versions can be redirected in app, 
      publisher policy, or machine configuration files. -->
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="10.0.0.0-12.0.0.0" newVersion="13.0.2000.0"/>
  </dependentAssembly>
</assemblyBinding>
<assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
  <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="CrystalDecisions.Shared" publicKeyToken="692FBEA5521E1304"/>
    <!-- Assembly versions can be redirected in app, 
      publisher policy, or machine configuration files. -->
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="10.0.0.0-12.0.0.0" newVersion="13.0.2000.0"/>
  </dependentAssembly>
</assemblyBinding>
<assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
  <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="CrystalDecisions.ReportSource" publicKeyToken="692FBEA5521E1304"/>
    <!-- Assembly versions can be redirected in app, 
      publisher policy, or machine configuration files. -->
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="10.0.0.0-12.0.0.0" newVersion="13.0.2000.0"/>
  </dependentAssembly>
</assemblyBinding>
<assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
  <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="CrystalDecisions.ReportAppServer.Controllers" publicKeyToken="692FBEA5521E1304"/>
    <!-- Assembly versions can be redirected in app, 
      publisher policy, or machine configuration files. -->
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="10.0.0.0-12.0.0.0" newVersion="13.0.2000.0"/>
  </dependentAssembly>
</assemblyBinding>
<assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
  <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="CrystalDecisions.ReportAppServer.DataDefModel" publicKeyToken="692FBEA5521E1304"/>
    <!-- Assembly versions can be redirected in app, 
      publisher policy, or machine configuration files. -->
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="10.0.0.0-12.0.0.0" newVersion="13.0.2000.0"/>
  </dependentAssembly>
</assemblyBinding>
<assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
  <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine" publicKeyToken="692FBEA5521E1304"/>
    <!-- Assembly versions can be redirected in app, 
      publisher policy, or machine configuration files. -->
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="10.0.0.0-12.0.0.0" newVersion="13.0.2000.0"/>
  </dependentAssembly>
</assemblyBinding>
</runtime>
</configuration>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try deleting both copies and reinstalling the runtime engine to clear all of this up.

Answer (score 0):

I am a web programmer and I work in version 2013 and crystal report. I am just solving this issue.

> First you go your asp.net project then click **bin** folder then you
>   see the crystal report dll save here. Delete all crystal report DLLs
>   in the bin folder and then restart your project. That's it.

Answer (score 0):

## admin should delete the wrong answers , merge the all posts with same questions and keep only correct answers

for this crystal report multiple version   problem at compile time is , search unwanted version reference in project for example search 13.5.2200.0 and delete all those lines , also delete the dll of unwanted version from the bin folder of your project.